# What should I do to make The search result return either the input was Upper or lower case?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

This Will return only when the user is available at the same case

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string UserSearch)
    {
        ViewData["GetUserDDetails"] = UserSearch;

        var UserQuery = from x in _context.Users select x;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserSearch))
            {
            UserQuery = UserQuery.Where(x => x.Username.Contains(UserSearch) || x.Email.Contains(UserSearch));
        }
        return View(await UserQuery.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
    }
```

Comment: Is this using Entity Framework? If so, what is the database provider?

Answer (score 0):

Use .ToLower() or .ToUpper() on both the query value and the subject value.

```
x => x.Username.ToLower().Contains(UserSearch.ToLower()) || ...
```

Comment: I think it would be better use to the Invariant versions of the methods, and to run the `UserSerach.ToLower()` method outside of the Where so it's not re-executed every loop.

Comment: Also, if this is an EF query, those methods might not be available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string UserSearch)
 {
    ViewData["GetUserDDetails"] = UserSearch;
    var UserQuery = from x in _context.Users select x;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserSearch))
    {
        UserQuery = UserQuery.Where(x => x.Username.ToUpper().Contains(UserSearch.ToUpper()) || x.Email.ToUpper().Contains(UserSearch.ToUpper()));
    }
    return View(await UserQuery.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
 }
```

Comment: thanks, it works but I realized my code will return no matter where the letter is any suggestion on making it on first letters of username and email